# Build an object while traversing a Binary Search Tree in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, binary-search-tree, javascript-objects, tree-traversal

The idea is to traverse a Binary Search Tree (BST) and build an object in the same method. The object represents the BST.

For example:

```
      20
   /      \
  5       60
   \     /  \
    10  40  90
         \
         50
           \
           55
```

I can generate this object while inserting an element to the BST, however, since I want to apply some balance algorithm into it, I won't need to insert any other node. I'll just need to get the final object with the result of the balancing.

The traverse method that came up was the Breadth-first travel. However, I didn't  figure out how the object would be built in a non-recursive approach since the Breadth-first travel is an iterative method.

For the example above the result object shall be this one shown below:

```
{
    val:20,
    l:{
        val:5,
        l:{},
        r:{
            val:10,
            l:{},
            r:{}
        }
    },
    r:{
        val:60,
        l:{
            val:40,
            l:{},
            r:{
                val:50,
                l:{},
                r:{
                    val:55,
                    l:{},
                    r:{}
                }
            }
        },
        r:{
            val:90,
            l:{},
            r:{}
        }
    }
}
```

What I have so far is:

```
Breadth_first = function (callback) {
    var q = [];
    q.push(root);
    while(q.length > 0){
        var node = q.shift();
        callback(node.level, node.value);
        if(node.leftChild.value !== null){
            q.push(node.leftChild);
        }
        if(node.rightChild.value !== null){
            q.push(node.rightChild);
        }
    }
}
```

The current method I'm using to build the object in such format is this one below:

```
insertNode = function (node, value, jsObj) {
    if (node.value === null) {
        node.leftChild = new Node();
        node.rightChild = new Node();

        node.value = value;

        jsObj.val = value;
        return true;
    }
    var nodeVal = parseInt(node.value, 10);
    if (value < nodeVal) {
        if(!jsObj.l.val)
            jsObj.l = {val:null, l:{}, r:{}};
        insertNode(node.leftChild, value, jsObj.l);
    } else if (value > nodeVal) {
        if(!jsObj.r.val)
            jsObj.r = {val:null, l:{}, r:{}};
        insertNode(node.rightChild, value, jsObj.r);
    }
}
```

Any guesses or clue would be appreciated!